# Firebase Auth in Background Service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, background-service

I have an android background service, on `onCreate()` function I run this

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("user@user.com", "password")
    .addOnCompleteListener((Executor)this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(Actions.LOG_TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

            } else {
                Log.w(Actions.LOG_TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

but it crashes. Why?
catch exception are

> network provider does not exist, provider doesn't exist: network
>
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zzb(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzde)'
>   on a null object reference
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zzb(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzde)'
>   on a null object reference

**EDIT**

Same problem putting code in onStart() function in MainActivity
(following this guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth)

Comment: is it reaching the else `Log.w(Actions.LOG_TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());` or crashing before?

Comment: I'm not sure this error has anything to do with the code you posted.   Is that the entire stack trace?

Comment: It crashes before onComplete() function, it crashes on mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(...)

Comment: have you enabled email/password method?

Comment: yes, I have a React Native app that do same things and it work perfectly

Comment: Have you tried to remove the cast by changing `(Executor)this` only with `this`?

Comment: Yes, but it gives me an error and I can't run the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emulator does not have Google Play Services installed.

Firebase Auth does not support devices without play services.

If you want to use Firebase you need to use Firebase Admin SDK.